# Kafka Streams DSL Predicate stream seperation

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

```
branch(new predicate{
 business logic 
 if(condition)
   return true
 else
   return false;
```

When the condition is false how to push to different stream. Currently creating another predicate which collects all other records which doesn't satisfy the above predicate in chain. Is there a way to do in same predicate?

Answer (score 2):

for that you need to pass also second predicate that always returns true

```
KStream<String, String>[] branches = kStream.branch(
    yourPredicate, 
    (String key, String value) -> true
);
branches[0].to(firstTopic);
branches[1].to(secondTopic);
```